# Get all text inside html tag with regex?

Tags: php, regex, function, dom, output

For example, I have the HTML:

```
<strong>this one</strong> <span>test one</span>
<strong>this two</strong> <span>test two</span>
<strong>this three</strong> <span>test three</span>
```

How get all text inside strong and span with regex?

Comment: Why not use [DomDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)?

Comment: The first step is to learn regular expressions. The second step is to apply your new-found knowledge using a function such as `preg_match`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`DOM`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and ***never*** use regular expressions for parsing HTML.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('strong') as $tag) {
   echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>";
  }
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('span') as $tag) {
    echo $tag->nodeValue."<br>";
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
this one
this two
this three
test one
test two
test three
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/132763)

---

### Why I shoudn't use Regular Expressions to parse HTML Content ?

> HTML is not a regular language and hence cannot be parsed by regular
> expressions. Regex queries are not equipped to break down HTML into
> its meaningful parts. so many times but it is not getting to me. Even
> enhanced irregular regular expressions as used by Perl are not up to
> the task of parsing HTML.

That article was from our **Jeff Atwood**. Read more [here.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) to load the HTML string and then use an XPath expression to get the required values:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

foreach ($xpath->query('//strong | //span') as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
this one
test one
this two
test two
this three
test three
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/132764)

Answer (score 0):

You can use captured groups. Here are some examples:

`<strong>([^\<]*)<\/strong>`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/sK5uF2

And

`<span>([^\<]*)<\/span>`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/vJ2kP3

In each of these, the first captured group is your text: `\1` or `$1`